# Как изменить размер layout?

Tags: android, android-layout

Почему gridlayout занимает лишь вертикальную полоску, хотя свойство layout_height = match_parent, а parent scrollview2 занимает большую часть экрана?

```
<GridLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:columnCount="3"
    android:addStatesFromChildren="false"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="false">

    <Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button7" />

    <Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button6"
        android:elevation="1dp" />

    <Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:onClick="gonext"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
        android:elevation="0dp" />

</GridLayout>

<TextView
    android:text="TextView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="19dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="19dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="39dp"
    android:id="@+id/textView2" />

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:animationCache="true"
    android:fadeScrollbars="true"
    android:id="@+id/scrollview2"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:layout_marginBottom="80dp">

    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </GridLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GridLayout` игнорирует параметр `android:layout_height="match_parent"` из-за того, что он вложен в `ScrollView` (аналогично, `GridLayout` вложенный в `HorizontalScrollView` будет игнорировать параметр `android:layout_width="match_parent"`). Это нормально.

Актуальная высота `GridLayout` определяется по размерам его дочерних элементов, и, вообще говоря, **она может быть больше** высоты его родительского элемента (именно поэтому этот атрибут и игнорируется).